# Broken Y-axis in Excel (NOTE: Pivot(!) diagram)

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, yaxis

I find some videos in fixing broken y-axis in a regular diagram in Excel - but is this possible for a Pivot-diagram which is created from a Pivot-table and has the 'filter in them'? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, no this is not possible for a pivot chart.

Comment: Thanks for insight - that's very disappointing and surprising though

Comment: The more you work with Excel, the more you see what it's good for and what it's not. Unfortunately I don't think pivot charts are customizable in this way.